# Publishing Custom List Items to a Separate Calendar List?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have built a Custom Sharepoint 2010 List (List A) which forms part of a workflow process.  The List has a number of date fields associated with it.  There is an entirely different Sharepoint site within the same site collection that has a Calendar List.  When an item in List A has a certain date field entered I want an instance of the List to appear in the Calendar List.  I am thinking I would add do this in an Event Receiver but I am not entirely sure how I would go about this.  Can anyone give me some pointers on this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to create a SPListItem within a calender depending on a field within another SPListItem.

There are different approaches how you could achieve this

- You could build a workflow for this scenario
- You could write a simple EventHandler

I think worklfow is fine and you could use SharePoint Designer to build it. So you don't have to write any code.